# Certain users cannot get to my server

Tags: linux, traffic

I am finding more and more users that report they cannot reach my server (website or services). Their tracert from that user looks like this:

```
Tracing route to domain.com [*.*.*.255] 
over a maximum of 30 hops: 
1 * * * Request timed out.
```

The server is up and functional and every else reports it is fine. But there are various users who cannot get to it. I have no firewall or anything that would block anyone.

Yes, the last part of the server IP is 255. Could this be causing it?
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r18539206-Last-octet-255-bug-on-Windows

Or would a certain ISP be denying traffic to my server?

Or something on their router level?

Answer (score 2):

That IP is definitely one I would avoid. Even if the end users devices can handle a .255, there's a chance some bad config anywhere between your server and your users might also be mishandling the traffic. Guessing it's a hold-over from the old class-based way of handling subnets.